# How to make a Python function that operates on two or more nested lists of the same shape?

Tags: python, list

I would like to apply an arbitrary function to two or more nested lists of the same shape. For instance if my function is:

```
def add(a, b):
    if "NULL" not in [a, b]:
        return a + b
    else:
        return "NULL"
```

and my inputs are:

```
input1 = [[1, 2, "NULL"], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
input2 = [[9, 8, "NULL"], [7, 6], [5, 4, 3, 2]]
```

Then I would like the output to be

```
output = [[10, 10, "NULL"], [10, 10], [10, 10, 10, 10]]
```

The inputs will always be nested one level deep, but the outputs ideally should be anything (for instance it could be nested deeper if the function was a "concatenate(a, b)" function)

Comment: Will the lists only ever be nested one level deep?

Comment: @PeterCollingridge Yes, at least in the input stage (perhaps the output could be nested deeper depending on the function applied)

Comment: If the lists are nested one level deep aways, why not `[func(val) for val in list_of_lists]` or event `map(func, list_of_lists)`, it would simplify your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def apply_f(a, b, f):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        return [apply_f(item_a, item_b, f) for item_a, item_b in zip(a, b)]
    else:
        return f(a, b)

result = apply_f(input1, input2, add)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists are always the right length (you can put a check for this), make your function recursive:

```
def add(a, b):

    if isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list):
        for a_sub, b_sub in zip(a, b):
            return [add(a_sub, b_sub) for a_sub, b_sub in zip(a, b)]

    elif "NULL" not in [a, b]:
        return a + b

    elif "NULL" in [a, b]:
        return "NULL"

    else:
        raise ValueError("Wrong input shapes")

input1 = [[1, 2, "NULL"], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
input2 = [[9, 8, "NULL"], [7, 6], [5, 4, 3, 2]]

add(input1, input2)
```

Output:

```
[[10, 10, 'NULL'], [10, 10], [10, 10, 10, 10]]
```